# mysql join not executing properly

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

```
$sql = mysql_query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM forum_posts 
    LEFT JOIN mymembers ON forum_posts.post_author_id = mymembers.id 
    WHERE section_id='$sid' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 25
");
$dynamicList = "";
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $reply_author_id = $row["post_author_id"];
    $author = $row["username"];
    $id = $row["id"];
    $anon = $row["anon"];
    $post_body=$row["post_body"];
    $post_author_id = $row["post_author_id"];
    $date_time = $row["date_time"];
    $thread_title = $row["thread_title"];
```

This is the mysql query I am executing. The problem is that both the table mymembers and forum_posts are having the id field so when I use $id and save the 'id' the id of the member is being stored in it. Following is the code I am displaying

```
$displayList .= '<a href="view_thread1.php?id=' . $id .'">
```

' . $thread_title . '' . $author .';

I want to save the id of the members in the $reply_author and the id of the thread into the $id variables.

Is there a way I can do it without changing the column names in the tables.

Done changing the query worked. Now the code looks like

```
$sql = mysql_query(
"SELECT forum_posts.post_author_id AS post_author_id, forum_posts.id AS id,    mymembers.username, forum_posts.anon,forum_posts.post_body,forum_posts.thread_title, forum_posts.date_time FROM forum_posts LEFT JOIN mymembers ON forum_posts.post_author_id=mymembers.id WHERE section_id='$sid' ORDER BY date_time DESC LIMIT 25");
```

Comment: You can alias the columns: `SELECT mymembers.id AS mymember_id, forum_posts.id AS postid, ...`

Answer (score 3):

The best practice way of doing it is to list out all of your fields in the query.

instead of using SELECT * change it to:

```
SELECT mymembers.id as id, forum_posts.id as fpID, etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to change the column name in the database, just rename it within your query:

```
SELECT members.id as reply_author
       members.username,
       [... other membes columns listed as the above ...]
       forum_posts.*
FROM   forum_posts
       LEFT JOIN mymembers
              ON forum_posts.post_author_id = mymembers.id
WHERE  section_id = '$sid'
ORDER  BY date_time DESC
LIMIT  25
```